# Dynamic iframe sending data to parent

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm looking for a SantaClaus gift in advance ... I have 2 scripts in my document, the first one ('init.js') is placed in the *head* part and the 2nd one ('index.js') just before closing */html* tag at the end of document. 'init.js' define a lot of vars usefull for 'index.js' loading later, once page's contents are loaded.

A dynamic iframe is builded in 'init.js':

```
let ifrm = document.createElement( 'iframe' );
ifrm.id = "getuserdata"; 
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "getuserdata.html");    
document.body.appendChild( ifrm );
```

Once the data are computed in iframe they're sended to parent:

```
parent.getVals(data);
```

Parent close the iframe and create the values for 'index.js'

```
function getVals(data){
   document.getElementById('getuser').outerHTML = "";
   delete document.getElementById('getuser');   
   let userdata = data;
 }
```

All is working perfectly but... but a console.log(data) in the iframe - to verify data is correct - displays the data value on the top of my console (normal, it's 'init') when the iframe is present. But when it disappears (iframe is deleted) the script continues to send the console.log for over 40 or 50 times after the page contents are loaded and the first 'index.js' console.log is displayed. Do you know why? It's not a very big problem but I can't understand why I receive all these notifications after closing the iframe.

Comment: You can use "message" event to share data from child to parent and parent to child.
If possible create a demo in codepen or jsfiddle.

Comment: yes but message is a lot of code on both parts for only a so small data. I use message when I need to talk to iframes all along the process of producting contents.

Comment: When ever we create an iframe, it creates another dom inside parent dom. So there is only one way to communicate is event. You can not directly communicate from child to parent or vice-versa.
You may try some hack, but i don't think will be a right apprach.

Comment: Yes it works, data produced in iframe is immediatly avalaible in parent, this is not the prob to solve. The prob to solve (or to explain) is: why this iframe once deleted continues to send 40 or 50 times its data to parent?